# Position link to the right but dont overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap (V3) grid layout with 2 columns.  Within the both columns I list "Title links" which can be short or long as well as an additional "Delete link".

I'd like the Delete link to float just to the right of the Title link if the Title fits within the window; however, for super long Titles that will be cut off, I'd like the Delete link to not expand past the container div's overflow and simply show up as far to the right as the container div allows (on top of the right-most part of the Title).

Currently the Delete links float to the right properly for small Titles, but get cut off if the Title link spills into the overflow area.

*Note that because this is the bootstrap grid layout the column widths do change.  I'm hoping for a CSS answer, but will use JS if necessary.

Here is an example fiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/obt42kmz/3/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 divNoOverflow">
    <div class="divNowrap">
      <a href="#">
        little title
      </a>
      <a href="#">DEL</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 divNoOverflow">
    <div class="divNowrap">
      <a href="#">
        long title long title long title long title long title
      </a>
      <a href="#">DEL</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.divNoOverflow {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.divNowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want. Do you want the title to collapse and always have DEL showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [calc()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) function of CSS this way:

```css
.divNoOverflow {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.full_width {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  max-width:calc(100% - 45px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.right {
  width:45px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 divNoOverflow">
    <div class="divNowrap">
      <a href="#">
        little title
      </a>
      <a href="#">DEL</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 divNoOverflow">
    <div class="full_width">
      <div class="left">
        <a href="#" class="">
        long title long title long title long title long title
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <a href="#" class="">DEL</a>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/y7f6d3f4/

However you can also use `float: right;` for your DEL link like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/4m41dtz4/